# How many ways there are to cover an $n \times n$ tiling with $2 \times 1$ dominoes?

Tags: tiling, statistical-mechanics

I came across the famous dimer problem in statistical physics and I'm struggling to come up with a mathematical formula for covering an $n \times n$ tiling with $2\times1$ dominoes? How does a combinatorical formula looks like for this problem?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A004003